# Why does the boundary shows different colors between black and white regions on a projector screen?

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

Original Question:

My friend took a picture of his screen from an angle (please see the attached picture) and found that the colors of the boundaries from white to black and ones from black to white are different.

Is there any explanation for this phenomenon?

Update/Correction: It turns out that this picture is **an image of a projector screen**...I am very sorry for the wrong information about the question.

[image]

Comment: Possible search term: [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), a type of [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [chromatic aberration](https://briankoberlein.com/blog/aberration/), which is the result of a lens deflecting different wavelengths of visible light by different angles, so that their images on the film/sensor don't quite line up.

[image]
[image]

If this is a crop from the edge of a larger photo, it may be real chromatic aberration in the camera. That's not possible if it's a full photo or a crop from the center, since the magnitude and direction of the effect should be a function of the distance from the center (as you can see in the horse image) and it isn't in your image.

It may also be fake chromatic aberration added to the original logo by the artist, displayed faithfully on the screen, and captured faithfully by the camera. It seems to be fashionable to add an aberration effect to digital artwork in the last few years. Many video games do it, for instance.

Comment: Thanks very much @benrg ! It turns out that this picture is an image of a projector screen. I think it is chromatic aberration indeed. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @skippyho That makes much more sense, I don't know why I didn't think of it.